# Method problems: Deleting duplicate chars in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, duplicates

So I am trying to delete duplicate chars in a partially filled array. The array is populated from a file located on my PC. My array population method is working fine; however, my duplicate deleting method is not. Here is my method:

```
    void deleteRepeated(char array[], int* numberUsed)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < *numberUsed ; x++) 
    {
        cout << "Positions used: " << *numberUsed << endl;
        for (int y = x+1; y < *numberUsed; y++ )
        {
            cout << "Positions used: " << *numberUsed << endl;
            if (array[y] == array[x])
            {
                cout << "Positions used: " << *numberUsed << endl;
                for (int z = y; z < *numberUsed; z++)
                    array[z] = array[z+1];
                y--; 
                *numberUsed--;
                cout << "Positions used: " << *numberUsed << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am passing the entire array, and the number of indices used in that array. The array length is 10, and my tests, I am using 6 out of those 10 with the chars: {'g', 'g', 'n', 'o', 'r', 'e'}. What am I doing wrong?

NOTE:  "cout << "Positions used: " << *numberUsed << endl" is being used to check if the method is correctly deleting or not. In the most inner loop where index is z, is where the method starts to go bonkers.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is STL an option for you?

Comment: Can  you use `std::string`?

Comment: @Andy Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @us2012: It eliminated only consecutive duplicates, as juanchopanza correctly pointed out. I somehow assumed that's what the OP wanted because of the example he provides, but in fact that's not necessarily the case.

Comment: Don't know what STL is Andy. Can't use something we haven't taken in school unfortunately. Can't use std::string either.

Comment: @Massa: Do you need to eliminate all duplicates or only consecutive duplicates?

Comment: @AndyProwl I still like your answer, just sort it first =P (if that is acceptable to the OP, of course).

Comment: @WhozCraig: he can't use STL unfortunately...

Comment: @AndyProwl bummer. Still liked the answer though, but yeah, no standard lib kinda takes the fun out of it.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thank you :-) And yes, hand-coding these things is not such a fun, but it probably makes sense that the first steps in programming are moved this way. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you find a dup you reduce the number chars used

```
*numberUsed--;
```

but remember this controlling the first loop index

```
for (int x = 0; x < *numberUsed ; x++)
```

so  try this

```
int count =*numberUsed;
for (int x = 0; x < count ; x++)
```

this way you visit all the original chars in the array.

Comment: +1, but I think there's at least one other problem in `array[z] = array[z+1];` - when `z == *numberUsed - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

(I wrote the first part of this answer before I read your comment about STL not being allowed, but I'll leave it anyways because I think it's rather neat code.)

You could use the functionality that the C++ standard library makes available to you. Use `std::string` instead of char arrays (that's nearly always a good idea), then you can do the following (note: C++11 only because of `unordered_set` and `std::begin`):

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

std::string uniquechars(const std::string& s) {
    std::unordered_set<char> uniquechars(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
    std::string newstring(std::begin(uniquechars), std::end(uniquechars));
    return newstring;
}

int main() {
    std::string teststr("thisisanexamplesentence");
    std::cout << "The unique characters of " << teststr << " are " << uniquechars(teststr) << std::endl;
}
```

Note that it doesn't keep the original order of the characters though, so if that's needed this does not work.

---

If you have to work without the standard library, you have to dig a bit deeper. @TimChild above already made a good start diagnosing what's wrong with your program, but there are more efficient solutions, for example keeping some kind of record of which characters you have already seen. As you're working with `char`s, I would consider a bit-field that can hold markers (extra overhead of 256/8=32 bytes) or if that's not too much, just a plain array of bools (extra overhead 256 bytes). As the latter is easier to implement and the code is more legible:

```
void deleteRepeated(char array[], int *numused) {
    bool seenthischar[256] = {false};
    char *readpointer = &array[0];
    char *writepointer = &array[0];
    int length = *numused;
    for ( ;readpointer <= &array[0] + length; readpointer++) {
      if (seenthischar[((unsigned char) *readpointer)]) {
        *numused--;
      } else {
        seenthischar[((unsigned char) *readpointer)] = true;
        *writepointer = *readpointer;
        writepointer++;
      }
    }
}
```

This only has one loop, so it only has to go through the array once, i.e. its time complexity is linear in the length of the input array.

Comment: +1 I like the dbl-pointer walker solution in this answer (bottom half). On the off-chance `char` is some whacked out bit-depth, `seenthischar` could be declared a little differently, but the algorithm is **solid**.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks! To be honest, I totally forgot about different bit depths (neither have I ever consciously used a system where char wasn't 8 bit), but I think I won't edit the code now because it doesn't really help the understanding of the algorithm.

Comment: Totally. I liked this so much I dropped my answer (which was close to this, but nowhere *near* as efficient in moving the data). Using considerably smaller mnemonics and judicious unary increments, it boils down [beautifully](http://ideone.com/fJ68Sc). To null-term the string you kinda have to include that as one of the chars, but no matter what algorithm is chosen that will be a problem. Really elegant solution. Had fun playing with it. Thanks!